# Relation two tables in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have made relation between Buku and Guest. I want to add link download ebook in guest's email. Field `link_dl` in table Buku.

In `common\models\Buku`

```
public function getGuest()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Guest::className(), ['id_buku' => 'id_buku']);
}
```

In `common\models\Guest`

```
public function getBuku()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Buku::className(), ['id_buku' => 'id_buku']);
}
```

In `Controller`

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        $value = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('myaccount@gmail.com')
        ->setTo($model->email)
        ->setSubject('Download Ebook')
        ->setTextBody($model->buku->link_dl) //link download ebook $model->relationName->field_name
        ->send();
        $model->save();
```

But I get an error,

> exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object'

What is the issue in here? Thankyou. **It's Solved**

Comment: It's because your guest->buku relation is one to many. Is that suppose to be like this or one to one?

Comment: because I think that one book can be used by many guest. am I wrong?

Comment: If one book can be used by many guest-you need to change in `Buku` model to `hasMany`. And if guest can have many books you need to keep in your `Guest` model the `hasMany`

Comment: Oh okay thankyou for u'r explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Your relation `getBuku` is declared as `One-to-Many`, so when you access buku with `$model->buku` you get array of `Buku` models.

If it's really a relation of type `One-to-Many` you have to choose (with any kind of logic, or simple get the 0 index) the `Buku` model you need like:

`->setTextBody($model->buku[0]->link_dl)`

If the relation suppose to be One-to-One, you need to change the relation in `Guest` model and then to access `link_dl` as in your code:

```
// common\models\Guest
public function getBuku()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Buku::className(), ['id_buku' => 'id_buku']);
}

// Controller
->setTextBody($model->buku->link_dl)
```

Comment: same solution !

Comment: because I think that one book can be used by many guest. am I wrong? I try to use `hasOne` in `common\models\Guest` and in `controller` I use `->setTextBody($model->buku->link_dl)` . But I'm still get the same error `exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object'`

Comment: Try to check if the model you access has buku relation. Look for the Guest model in your db, see if buku_id is not null, and then check if this Buku exists in your db.